# Como passar dados de checkbox por FILTER_SANITIZE em PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, mysqli

Não estou conseguindo passar os valores do *checkbox* no PHP.
Tenho um único arquivo `home.php` com o seguinte código:

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
include_once("conexao.php");

$btnCadastrar = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'btnCadastrar', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if($btnCadastrar){

    $dados_rc = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_DEFAULT);

    $erro = false;

    $dados_st = array_map('strip_tags', $dados_rc);
    $dados = array_map('trim', $dados_st);

    $checkbox = $dados['ch'];
    foreach($checkbox as $id_servico){
        $query = "INSERT INTO os_servico (id_os, id_servico, criado) VALUES (
        '$id_os',
        '$id_servico',
        NOW())";
        $result_query = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    }

}   
?>
```

Dá os seguintes erros:

```
Notice: Undefined index: ch in C:\xampp\htdocs\site2\home.php on line 16
Warnig: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() C:\xampp\htdocs\site2\home.php on line 17
```

O que poderia estar causando o erro? será que é na passagem do POST?

Comment: Já verificou qual é o valor de `$dados` e se deveria existir o índice `ch`?

Comment: ? não entendi! não tenho que ter um array das checkbox selecionadas e chama-las pelo ch[]? não consigo ver outra forma de faze-lo.

Comment: Faça um `var_dump($dados)` se não está utilizando nenhuma ferramenta de debug (recomendado).

Comment: Fiz! Resultado:
array(1) { ["btnCadastrar"]=> string(9) "Cadastrar" }

Comment: ou quando seleciona algum checkbox: array(2) { ["ch"]=> string(0) "" ["btnCadastrar"]=> string(9) "Cadastrar" }

Comment: Bom, se existe o índice `ch` no *array*, não faz sentido dar a mensagem de *undefined index* que citou na pergunta. Mas no geral a pergunta está confusa. Qual era o resultado esperado quando utilizou a função `filter_input_array`? Por que usou `FILTER_DEFAULT`?

Comment: então, até existe o ch[ ], porém repare que a string esta zerada, é como se passasse a seleção, mas não o valor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue a solução:

```html
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
include_once("conexao.php");

$btnCadastrar = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'btnCadastrar', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if($btnCadastrar){

    $checkbox = $_POST['ch'];
    foreach($checkbox as $id_servico){
        $query = "INSERT INTO os_servico (id_os, id_servico, criado) VALUES (
        '$id_os',
        '$id_servico',
        NOW())";
        $result_query = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    }

}   
?>
```